# how to add mongodb existing json data to meteor application?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor project folder and one more folder with mongodb json files. Now how will i install these files to my meteor application so that the mongodb collections gets created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your project folder, Be sure to run the meteor project in another terminal

```
mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --db meteor path_to_mongodb_json_folder
```

this command will allow to restore the collections in your project